# Error while running rosserial on bluetooth

Tags: ros, wireless, bluetooth, rosserial-arduino, rosserial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have connected HC-05 to Arduino mega and initialized the bluetooth connection through port rfcomm0.
I had uploaded the [code](http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_arduino/Tutorials/Blink) to arduino and When i try running rosserial node to subscribe the message as

```
$rosrun rosserial_python serial_node.py _port:=/dev/rfcomm0
```

I have bumped into the error below

```
netceilo@netceilo-OptiPlex-780:~$ rosrun rosserial_python serial_node.py _port:=/dev/rfcomm0 _baud:=57600
[INFO] [WallTime: 1486073151.351080] ROS Serial Python Node
[INFO] [WallTime: 1486073151.354630] Connecting to /dev/rfcomm0 at 57600 baud
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1486073168.457418] Unable to sync with device; possible link problem or link software version mismatch such as hydro rosserial_python with groovy Arduino
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1486073183.458364] Unable to sync with device; possible link problem or link software version mismatch such as hydro rosserial_python with groovy Arduino
```

How to get around this issue, i had checked the baud rates and it seems to be fine and also there is no issue in code as the code is working well with usb port.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/253547/error-while-running-rosserial-on-bluetooth/) by [Kishore Kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/20863/kishore-kumar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 173 on 2017-02-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) on 2017-02-03**:
Is your bt connection full duplex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you set the right boad in the Arduino code (I see on the Linux site 9600)? Do you use the Right Serialport on the Arduino?

look at this Anser

```
http://answers.ros.org/question/206972/baud-rate-parameter-in-rosserial_python-arduino/
```

may this help

Greet

---

Originally posted by [duck-development](https://answers.ros.org/users/22870/duck-development/) with karma: 1999 on 2017-02-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kishore Kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/20863/kishore-kumar/) on 2017-02-02**:
Yes i Tried that fix as well but it didnt help

**Comment by [duck-development](https://answers.ros.org/users/22870/duck-development/) on 2017-02-11**:
Did you Desolder the USB/Uart Chip from the Arduino, cause you can use ether usb or bluetooth but not the both at the same time.

the problem ist the TX line. only one Chip can drive it.

Had the same problem wih the Bluetooth Uart Bridge and my 3D printer.